# C++. Как избавиться от nan?

Tags: c++, nan

В задании нужно вычислить ln (tg x) с обработкой исключительных ситуаций. Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

for(int i = 0; i<50; i++)
{
    try
    {
        int temp = rand()%41 - 20; // x від -20 до 20

        for(int n = -7; n < 7; n++)
        {
            double k, t;
            k = 3.14*n;
            t = (3.14/2) + (3.14*n);

            if((temp <= k)&&(temp >= t))
                throw (double)temp;

        }

            cout << "x = " << temp << "\t" << "y = ";
            cout << log(tan(temp)) << endl; //ln(tg(x))

    }

    catch(double a)
    {
       cout << "x does not belong to the domain of a function: ";
       cout << a;
    }
}
```

}

При компиляции временами выдаёт nan в y. Я в принципе возможно догадываюсь где ошибка (из-за `for(int n = -7; n < 7; n++)` выкидывает несколько "вариантов" temp потому catch не реагирует? ну, или ошибка где-то ещё), но никак не могу придумать её решение. Помогите, пожалуйста. Я начинающий, так что прошу пояснения подетальнее или хотя бы пример кода, как это можно исправить.

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите. Не вычислять, заранее зная, что не получится? Перехватывать и не выводить NaN? Как именно вы хотели бы обрабатывать ситуацию? Просто "мне надо, чтоб при вычислении `log(-1)` не было ошибки, сами понимаете, не ответ. Так можно просто написать `log(abs(tan(x)))` и не мучиться :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может, заменить

```
cout << "x = " << temp << "\t" << "y = ";
cout << log(tan(temp)) << endl; //ln(tg(x))
```

на

```
if (tan(temp) > 0) {
    cout << "x = " << temp << "\t" << "y = ";
    cout << log(tan(temp)) << endl; //ln(tg(x))
    }
else throw double(temp);
```

?

Comment: Nan исчезло, но код всё равно не работает, как надо.

Comment: А как это - как надо? Поясните. Кстати, этот же вопрос в комментарии @Harry - что вы хотите получить?

Comment: Кажется, понял, что вы хотите, чтоб генерировалось исключение? тогда посмотрите, я добавил строчку `else`.

Comment: Получилось! Огромное Вам спасибо!